# Conversation/Threaded message view in roundcube 1.0.1 is disabled

Tags: webmail, roundcube

I want use Conversation/Threaded message view in roundcube 1.0.1 but the appropriate button is always disabled.

[image: Disabled Threads button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMAP server must support the capability THREAD (THREAD=REFERENCES)

Answer (score 3):

The function is there: Settings -> Folders -> Inbox (or other folder) -> List view mode -> Threads

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For servers that do not offer THREAD (THREAD=REFERENCES) capability, you can still enable the functionality by using MyRoundcube Plugin imap_threads. Basically, download the plugin, enable it and off you go.

http://myroundcube.com/myroundcube-plugins/imap_threads-plugin

Comment: Link do not exists and looks like plugin also.

Comment: The link ask you to install unknown application