# Gmail doesn't provide threaded view and THREAD (THREAD=REFERENCES) capability?

Tags: gmail, imap, gmail-imap, roundcube

I connected my gmail account to Roundcube(program for managing emails) and "Threaded view" is grayed out. According to this: [Conversation/Threaded message view in roundcube 1.0.1 is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779707/conversation-threaded-message-view-in-roundcube-1-0-1-is-disabled) It means gmail does not provide THREAD (THREAD=REFERENCES) capability. It's weird because if you open gmail like you normally would (it's native interface without Roundcube), then it has got threaded view by default. So.. How is this possible? Does gmail use some other mechanism to group messages in threads?

Comment: This question (or the linked question) do not appear to be about programming and thus are not suited for stackoverflow.  You should ask further questions on serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 3):

Just because it supports a threaded view in the webmail component (which is completely different from the IMAP server) doesn't mean it supports a certain IMAP extension.

Gmail has their own way of tracking threads: the [X-GM-THRID](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_the_gmail_thread_id_x-gm-thrid), which exposes their own threading information.